# ActiveRecord through association with where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to make an ActiveRecord association for backers of a campaign.

There is a Payments table with 3 relevant fields:

```
campaign_id, status, backer_id
```

I only want backers if they have on of the following statuses: 
authorized charged released rejected offline

I tried to do this with the following in the Campaign class:

```
has_many :backers , through: :payments, -> { where payments.status: %w(authorized charged released rejected offline) }
```

But its not working.  I'd greatly appreciate any help. And if I need to add any more info please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you're using on `where` does not look correct.  If you prefer hash syntax use:

```
has_many :backers, 
  through: :payments, 
  -> { where(payments: { status: %w(authorized charged released rejected offline) }) }
```

Comment: Hi vee. thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately its not working for me.  I should've mentioned originally this is a rails 3.2 app.  Could that be my issue?

Comment: If you are using Ruby 1.9, this should work.  Another option is to place `where` condition as the value of `conditions:` key.  E.g.: `has_many :backers, 
  through: :payments, 
  conditions: { where(payments: { status: %w(authorized charged released rejected offline) }) }`.  Please post the error log you're getting.  That'll speed up debugging.

Comment: Tried the latest and that provided a far better error message. Now its clear what the error is but still don't know the fix.    : 3] pry(main)> Campaign.last.backers
  Campaign Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "campaigns".* FROM "campaigns" ORDER BY "campaigns"."id" DESC LIMIT 1
   (0.4ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "campaigns" WHERE "payments"."status" IN ('authorized', 'charged', 'released', 'rejected', 'offline')
PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "payments"
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "campaigns"  WHERE "payments"."status" ...
                                                ^

Comment: @Tom, AR should have taken care of the join `joins(:payments)`, not sure why its not there.  Can you confirm that you have `has_many :payments` in this model.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a scope:

```
scope :backers_with_status, ->(backers){ joins(backers).where("payments.status IN (?)" %w(authorized charged released rejected offline)) }
```

Comment: Did you try actually running this code? It appears to have syntax errors.